# How to attach bootbox onclose event?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I have this part of code that uses [bootboxjs](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html)

```
function BootBox(title,message,callback) {
    var box = bootbox.dialog({
        show: false,
        backdrop: true,
        animate: false,
        title: title,
        message: message,
        buttons: {
            cancel: {
                label: 'Cancel',
                className: 'btn-warning'
            },
            save: {
                label: 'Save',
                className: 'btn-success',
                callback: callback
            }
        }
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) { // HOW TO UNREGISTER THIS EVENT HOOK?
        if(box && e.keyCode == 27) box.modal("hide");
    });
    return box;
}
```

the keyup method, called too many times when I call many `BootBox()`, how to unregister the keyup event hook when closing the box?

**EDIT**

Nevermind, i got a better way, change `document` to `box`, now the event won't be called multiple times when `BootBox` function called more than once

```
    $(box).keyup(function(e) { 
        if(box && e.keyCode == 27) box.modal("hide").remove(); 
    });
```

Comment: Actually `box` will ever be true :) its just hidden and not removed so its not nessesary to use it in your if statements :)

Comment: I see, I thought you wanted it in document :)

Comment: @deW1 XD document never touched anyway when box has the backdrop, thanks for the tips @ Dwza

Comment: If you want to use box in this way, try `.remove()` (what actually is jquery) and if you use jquery... you could also simply use `hide()` instead of `modal('hide')`

Comment: I've tried it, `hide()` doesn't work, the backdrop still there.. @Dwza

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$("#box").on( "hide" , function() {
    $(document).off( "keyup" , "#box" );
});
```

Explanation:

"keyup" is the event

"#box"  is the selector so it only counts for the #box

Comment: btw, would it also disconnect any other `$(document).keyup` event hook that not related to the box? if it so, it would be bad..

Comment: just add the selector to the `.off` event.

Comment: thanks for the inspiration XD i got a better way to prevent the event hook called multiple times when i call `BootBox` function more than once

Comment: for bootstrap 3 use "hidden.bs.modal" event

Answer (score 0):

use event.stopPropagation() - http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/
In your case

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) { // HOW TO UNREGISTER THIS EVENT HOOK?
    if(box && e.keyCode == 27) box.modal("hide");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```